# encoded JPEG and JPEG differene

Tags: jpeg, output, encode, encoder

I have a JPEG file in a `char* buffer` from a jpeg encoder. Assume if I write it correctly to file it'll be pic.jpg. Say then I read in using `ifstream` from pic.jpg and store it in `char* buffer2`.

What's the difference between these two buffers, if there's any?

(The reason I'm asking is that, I have jpeg file in a `char * buffer` from a jpeg decoder and I need to write it to disk. But using the system `file descripter` and `write()` method in `fcntl.h` doesn't write it out properly... I can open the picture, but it's very obvious that the colors are off. Please assume that the picture has valid colors when it was outputed from the decoder, because I can write directly from decoder to disk and everything's fine. It's just I need to put it in a `char* buffer` for other purposes, and I need to verify that `buffer` has valid data before further processing.)

Answer (score 0):

The description you are giving implies that you are reading Y component(responsible for brightness) properly and not reading UV components (responsible for color) properly.This looks like either you are not writing the entire decoded data to disk or you are not reading the entire decoded data from disk while rendering(displaying). Best place to start is check the size of decoded data (size = height * width of original jpg image).

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch6/Images/ch6_image_downsampling.jpg